# GridView in WIndowsPhone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

[image]

Hi Everyone, I want to create an GridView like this in windows phone 8.1
1.GridView is not supporting AutoGenerateColumns

[image]
This is the outpuit i got. Here i tried to obtain the data from Sqlite and binded to the ItemsSource property of gridview in gridview load event of the cs file.

```
My code:
<Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentRoot" Margin="19,9.5,19,0">
<GridView x:Name="grdUser" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Height="auto"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="auto" Loaded="grdUser_Loaded">
<GridView.HeaderTemplate><DataTemplate>
<Border Margin="5" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1"><Grid ><Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/><ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/><ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/></Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock Text="UserName" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="UserPassword" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text="CreatedDate" Grid.Column="2"/>
                                        </Grid></Border>                                             </DataTemplate></GridView.HeaderTemplate><GridView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Border Margin="5" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1"><Grid><Grid.ColumnDefinitions><ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/><ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/><ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/></Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="tbUserName" Text="{Binding UserName}"/>
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="tbUserPassword" Text="{Binding UserPassword}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="tbCreatedDate" Text="{Binding CreationDate}" Grid.Column="2"/>
                                        </Grid></Border></DataTemplate></GridView.ItemTemplate></GridView> </Grid>
```

Is there any other controls for kind of requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the MyToolkit library, it has a datagrid control that could be ok for you.

https://github.com/MyToolkit/MyToolkit/wiki/DataGrid

Comment: Is there any other links. or Can you explain the mistake that i made